# UIImage to NSData for Core Data in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, ios10, nsdata

So previously, in Swift 2.2 I could use `Entity.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "Image Name")!)`

But now in Swift 3.0 it appears that we now have to use an extra step. `Entity.image = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "Image Name")!))` Or the object equivalent of `UIImage(name: "Image Name")`

Is there a new way in Swift 3.0 to go from `UIImage` to `NSData`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "hallo.png") {
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) as NSData?
}
```

Comment: That did the job. What I found interesting is it doesn't work when I use as! or as?. It told me that Casting from Data? to NSData always fails. I'm curious why it's able to work with it is as NSData?

Comment: what if you don't care type it is, you just want its raw Data representation

Comment: It tells me Core Data expects Data, not NSData

Answer (score 7):

For safe execution of code, use if-let block with Data, as function UIImagePNGRepresentation returns, optional value.

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "Hello.png") {
    if let data:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
       // Handle operations with data here...         
    }
}
```

> Note: **Data** is Swift 3 class. Use Data instead of NSData with
>   Swift 3

Generic image operations (like png & jpg both):

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "Hello.png") {
        if let data:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
               handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
        } else if let data:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0) {
               handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
        }
}

*******
func handleOperationWithData(data: Data) {
   // Handle operations with data here...
}
```

By using extension:

```
extension UIImage {

    var pngRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
    }

    var jpegRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)
    }
}

*******
if let img = UIImage(named: "Hello.png") {
      if let data = img.pngRepresentationData {
              handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
      } else if let data = img.jpegRepresentationData {
              handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
      }
}

*******
func handleOperationWithData(data: Data) {
     // Handle operations with data here...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 4, it is a lot easier:

```
let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0)
```

Of course, compression quality is a variable you set. 0 for most compression and 1 for least compression.

Comment: aditionally you have
    photo.pngData()

Answer (score 1):

Using UIImagePNGRepresentation to convert `UIImage` to `Data` may sometimes result in distorted images when you convert the data back, because some essential metadata is removed from the original data in the initial conversion.

After some research I ended up with the following code to convert `UIImage` to `Data`:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "whatever")
var data: Data?

if let cgImage = image.cgImage, cgImage.renderingIntent == .defaultIntent {
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)
}
else {
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  PNG or JPG image as Data.

For PNG
self.imgProfilePic.image!.pngData()

For JPEG
self.imgProfilePic.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)  // Quality min = 0.0 to max = 1.0

Answer (score -1):

Use as extension to get PNG or JPG imageData as NSData.

```
extension UIImage {
    var jpegRepresentationData: NSData! {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)! as NSData   // QUALITY min = 0 / max = 1
    }
    var pngRepresentationData: NSData! {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)! as NSData
    }
}

//use
imageView.image!.jpegRepresentationData or
imageView.image!.pngRepresentationData
```